# Can't send email through Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to use this script as a simple boolean that checks for a file, and sends a success email, or a failure email. But I cannot for the life of me figure out why it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "xxxx@xxxxx.com"
$Password = "xxxxxxx"
$to = "xxx@xxxxx.net"

if ( ([System.Io.fileinfo]'E:\GD Backup Folder\backup\Backup_*.zip').LastWriteTime.Date -ne [datetime]::Today )    {
            $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $message.subject = "Backup Successful"
            $message.body = "Backup was successful."
            $message.to.add($to)
            $message.from = $username

            $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
            $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
            $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
            $smtp.send($message)
            write-host "Mail Sent"
}else{
            $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $message.subject = "Backup Unsuccessful"
            $message.body = "Backup was NOT Successful - File Not Found"
            $message.to.add($to)
            $message.from = $username

            $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
            $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
            $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
            $smtp.send($message)
            write-host "Mail Sent"
}
```

Comment: How do you even manage to get this bit to work?
[System.Io.fileinfo]'E:\GD Backup Folder\backup\Backup_*.zip'

Comment: It simply is looking for a file that has the same date as today, and will send an email if yes, or if no.

Maybe I can't use a wildcard there?

Comment: Try running that single snippet of code on your command line.
[System.Io.fileinfo]'E:\GD Backup Folder\backup\Backup_*.zip'

Comment: Oh .. Right. So I can't use wildcards in that spot. That's weird it never gave me an error before. It just ran like normal.

I figured I would do it the easy way, instead of trying to match one particular file. I thought it would be easier to just look at all of them.

Comment: My files are generated in a separate script with the filenames looking like this: Lytec_Backup_02192015.zip I am simply trying to validate that the last one, today's, is present then fire an email stating yes or no.

Comment: Since the actual file name is known you could use Test-Path.

if(Test-Path -Path "E:\GD Backup Folder\backup\Backup_$([DateTime]::Today.ToString('MMddyyyy')).zip")
{
    "Yup, it's there."
}
else
{
    "Nope, not there."
}

Comment: That boolean certainly works much better THANKS!

But it still won't fire an email. lol fml

Answer (score 0):

Send email with attachment using powershell -

```
     $EmailTo = "udit043.ur@gmail.com"  // abc@domain.com
     $EmailFrom = "udit821@gmail.com"  //xyz@gmail.com
     $Subject = "zx"  //subject
     $Body = "Test Body"  //body of message
     $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
     $filenameAndPath = "G:\abc.jpg"  //attachment
     $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
     $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
     $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
     $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
     $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
     $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("udit821@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx");    // xxxxxx-password
     $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Comment: I actually could never get this working for whatever reason. I tried your way as well, early on.

I ended up rewriting the whole thing in Python. Worked first try. :: shrugs ::